# How to set HTML attributes with variables?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In my HTML I have a lot of repeated elements with quite a few attributes each and most of them are the same. It's taking up a lot of space and I could clean up the code if I could just set the attributes as a variable and use that variable in all my elements. So is there a way to do this?

For example one of my elements look like this,

```html
<button className='btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle' style={{ margin: "5px" }} type='button' data-bs-toggle='dropdown' aria-expanded='false'>
  Delete
</button>
```

And there are at least 10 other buttons with the exact same set of attributes and takes up almost 100 lines worth of space. Is there a way I can set the attributes in one place then apply it to every element to save space?

Comment: `className`? That's the property in JavaScript but it's `class` in HTML. Are you using JSX and React?

Comment: AFAIK no you can't do that, and the `className` and `style` attribute will change at compile time, so you cannot add it using variable because react will never know while compiling it, What you can do is to create component for your customised button

Comment: Sounds like you could just create a component

Comment: Do you still need help with this question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are reusing a collection of html attributes, here are two ways you could handle this:

1. Save the attributes into an object and spread the object onto each `<button>` that uses them.
2. Create a `<CustomButton>` component and encapsulate the shared attributes in the component. Because each attribute is exposed as a prop in the component interface, each prop/attribute has a default value but can be overwritten if necessary.

---

```
// #1
const defaultButtonProps = {
  className: "btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle",
  style: { margin: "5px" },
  type: "button",
  "data-bs-toggle": "dropdown",
  "aria-expanded": "false"
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {/* #1 */}
        <button {...defaultButtonProps}>Delete</button>
        <button {...defaultButtonProps}>Save</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        {/* #2 */}
        <CustomButton />
        <CustomButton>Save</CustomButton>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

// #2
const CustomButton = ({
  className = "btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle",
  style = { margin: "5px" },
  type = "button",
  dataBsToggle = "dropdown",
  ariaExpanded = "false",
  children = "Delete"
}) => {
  return (
    <button
      className={className}
      style={style}
      type={type}
      data-bs-toggle={dataBsToggle}
      aria-expanded={ariaExpanded}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

---

[image: Edit kind-ellis-0kejip]